# Is there a nicer way to organize shares in Windows' Computer Management Console (w/ respect to their local hierarchy structure)? Alternatives?

Tags: network-shares, shared-folders

Is there a way to custom organize Shares in Windows' Computer Management Console (or better yet organize in respect to the hierarchy that they exist in on their local server (I know that the Computer Mgmt Console is at least aware of this structure because it list the shares' "Folder Path"s in the UI))? Some other common tool that can be used for viewing and managing shares in a hierarchy-respecting way?

We have Samba shares on a CentOS7 fileserver that use [ADS security](https://www.howtoforge.com/samba_ads_security_mode).
They share various folders that are *locally* structured like...

```
share1
    share11
        datafolder111
            <datafiles>
        datafolder112
            <datafiles>
        datafolder113
            <datafiles>
        ...
    share12
        ...
    share13
        ...
    ...
share2
    share21
        ...
    share22
        ...
    share13
        ...
    ...
...
```

We manage the individual share folders' security/access (eg. which AD groups have what types of security permissions) by connecting to the fileserver via the Computer Management Console on a separate Windows Server 2012 R2 machine. (We individually manage the shareX and shareXX folders because we have situations where a team may "own" shareX, but only certain members are allowed to access shareX[A-B]).

[image]

The problem is that for large numbers of shares (which we have), this *flat list structure* presented in the Computer Mgmt UI is very messy and makes the shares harder to manage. Being able to view the shares in a similar structure to how they exist on the fileserver would makes things much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since shares can be sorted in alpha order in the console, one solution is to use a naming convention similar to the parentX-childXY naming in the example that describes the hierarchy like...

```
parent1
    parent1_child1
        <datafiles and subdirs>
    parent1_child2
        <datafiles and subdirs>
    ...
```

So, presently, my `smb.conf` file looks like...

```
[parent1__child1]
    path = /parent1/child1
    read only = no

[parent1__child2]
    .
    .
    .
.
.
.
```

...and this works out OK when sorting by Share Name in the Windows Computer Mgmt console.

Note that (I think) there is a maximum 255 character length for the actual paths and a 80 character limit on Samba share names (so keep that in mind as you may want to have the paths themselves follow some naming convention (I applied it to the shares only because it seemed nicer when having to organize them when they actually mounted on a desktop)).